# How can I access visitor Web browser history using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, webclient, browser-sync

Can I access visitor Web browser history when he visits on my website using javascript or any other way?

Comment: No. That would be a violation of privacy.

Comment: You can use the `document` object. It will give you bunch of information about the user. Directly you probably won't have access to the user `history` as its a security issue. However you can use the `history` API to `push`/`pop` the users history.

Comment: ok, could you suggest me the way to get access?